# How hard is it to get opencv working across different platforms without cmake?

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake, centos

I am working on a project that doesn't use cmake. 
How hard is it to create a setup script for opencv that doesn't rely on cmake? How hard is it to have it work across different platforms (linux, osx etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it is easier to use CMake, OpenCV is prepared to use CMake. It loads all libreries in a very easy way. Also you can activate and deactivate the different libreries using ccmake. It enters a menu where you can manage this.

Also you can use cmake in ios directly, as well as in linux. For android for example you would need to use use the [NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html), that calls the c++ code from Java (Android)

Comment: To conclude, if you can use cmake, then use it. If you do not have any other option it will cost you a much more